# Compile error "Method or data member not found" with .ReadReceiptRequested in CDO mail

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

In the following code the `.ReadReceiptRequested` line gives

> "Compile error: Method or data member not found"

```vb
Dim Mail As New Message
Dim Config As Configuration: Set Config = Mail.Configuration
Config(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort

With Mail
    .To = str
    .from = """test"" <test@myemail.com>"
    .Subject = str_subject
    .CreateMHTMLBody email_filename
    .ReadReceiptRequested = True
    .Send
End With
```

It works without the `.ReadReceiptRequested` line.

Comment: What is the type of `Mail`?

Comment: `Dim Mail As New Message`
`Dim Config As Configuration: Set Config = Mail.Configuration`
`Config(cdoSendUsingMethod) = cdoSendUsingPort` It works fine without the `.ReadReceiptRequested`-line.

Comment: `.ReadReceiptRequested` is from the Outlook Object Library, which is not what you're using.

Comment: Is there a workaround? Or a solution with the email sending method i'm using now?

Comment: Looks like you're using CDO? Haven't used myself but from what I glean it's fairly limited.